# Dictionary add creating two entries with flipped key value pair

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I am trying to do a simple operation of adding item to dictionary after reading .resx file. Eg: the first row in the resx file is  Name: Button and Value: Convertir.  I see that the item is added to dictionary trans twice with flipped key value pair, for execution of one foreach loop. i.e. 
Count[0] {[Button, Convertir]}  and
Count[1] {[Convertir, Button}].

I just want the item to be added once as [0] {[Button, Convertir}]. Same is happening with Dicitionay _translations.

Following is the piece of code.

```
private void Add2Dictionary(CultureInfo cultureInfo, Assembly assembly, ResXResourceReader rsxr)
{

    Dictionary<string, string> trans = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    _translations[cultureInfo] = trans;

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rsxr)
    {
        string Key = entry.Key.ToString();
        string Value = entry.Value == null ? string.Empty : entry.Value.ToString();               

         trans.Add(Key, Value);
         _translations[_enCultureInfo].Add(Value, Key);
     }
}
```

where _translations[cultureInfo] is of below type and value of cultureInfo is es-US

```
Dictionary<CultureInfo, Dictionary<string, string>> _translations = new Dictionary<CultureInfo, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Please help guide.

Comment: It should be key , value : Add(Value, Key);

Comment: `trans` and `_translations[_enCultureInfo]` both refer to the same dictionary - was that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding it twice, once to the trans Dictionary and then to the _translations Dictionary

```
trans.Add(Key, Value);
//The value in _translations is a Dictionary, so this assigns the dictionary to the key _enCultureInfo
_translations[_enCultureInfo] = trans;
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but going by your question and variable declaration this is possibly what you are looking for.

EDIT: Looking at it again, I'm not sure if you need the value in _translations to be a Dictionary or did you intend it to be a simple `List<string>`?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Yes i just got the answer before your ping. based off of previous comment posted. This was the exact solution modified. Thanks!!